# Cluster system architecture?

Tags: java, architecture, cluster-computing

I would like to develop application for ~500 active users (sessions at one time). System would not process any massive calculations. It will be simple read/write to database solution. However, to application would be uploaded about 50mb of data daily per user. (it would be analysed and clean by other application every day when non users will be active). Actually I'm working on design of this application and I've got few questions about that.

1. Should I consider developing application working in some cluster with load balance or one server will handle this amount of usage?
2. If yes, is there any guidelines about developing application to work in cluster? Is there any difference than developing single server application?
3. Should I be worried about database of this application? What problems should I expect when 2 servers will read/write data to single database at same time? Maybe it also should work in cluster?

I would be pleased for any help and/or articles about design this mid size applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This depends on you NFR (non functional requirements). Next to load balancing, a cluster provides higher availability.
2. You'll have to make your back-end state-less so that requests from the same user can end up on another node without the user noticing. This makes it more expensive to build scaling software. So consider your options carefully.
3. Accessing a database from multiple servers is not different than accessing it from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, I think using an infrastructure provider that lets you easily scale (up or down) your application is always a big plus and can help you save money. My main experience with this kind of providers is with Amazon Web Services (AWS).

I don't know precisely what technology you are planning to use, but a general setup like that on AWS would make sense to me is:

- A set of EC2 instances (= virtual servers) running behind an ELB (a load balancer)
- An auto scaling group containing the EC2 instances. You can look it up, but an auto scaling group basically lets you automatically add and remove instances depending on various factors (server load, disk I/O, etc.)
- The use of RDS for your database. It supports multiple DBMS such as MySQL and Oracle. It also provides you with nice features such as replication, automated backups and monitoring.
- The use of CodeDeploy to deploy your application on the servers

(I'm voluntarly using the AWS names so that you can read the documentation if you are interested.)

This would basically let you scale to a lot more than 500 concurrent users if needed, and could save you some money when you are handling less users. Note that auto scaling groups can also be scheduled. For instance : *« I want at least 5 instances during the day (max 50), but you can go down to 2 (and still up to 50) between 1am and 4am »*

The services I mentionned are quite widely documented, so you can look it up if you'd like some more specific details.

I won't discuss in detail your two other questions because I'm not an expert on the subject, but the database can indeed be a bottleneck since it may involve a lot of I/Os.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for help, but that's not what we are looking for. We are not going to host our app at client's servers.